# Spring-boot-admin: App status remains "UP" after app crashes

Tags: monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot admin is a great tool to make the health and metrics of my spring boot application (in my case a web-server) available. I've followed the  [reference guide](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.1) and could finally get it to run, with one exception though: The server doesn't seem to recognize if the client crashes/goes down.

For testing I currently use separate applications, both running on the same host. In the final version I plan to have multiple clients (running on separate IP addresses) to register with a single server running on its separate IP).

**Server** (a separate spring boot project)

*pom.xml*

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

*application.properties:*

```
server.port=8081
```

*MyMain:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAdminServer
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Client** (my WebApp to be monitored):

*pom.xml:*

```
...
<!-- SPRING BOOT ADMIN (CLIENT) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

*application.properties:*

```
server.port=8080
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.boot.admin.client.management-url=http://localhost:8081
spring.boot.admin.client.service-url=http://localhost:8080
spring.boot.admin.client.name=my-rest-app
```

With this setup I can connect to http://localhost:8080 to get my web-app or to http://localhost:8081 to see the admin/monitoring UI. The status shows UP and I can browse the mem/heap/traces/...

The issue now is, that if I kill the web-app the status remains UP.

1. From the description I would have assumed that the server property `spring.boot.admin.monitor.period` is checking every 10s the status of the clients app.
2. Or, do I require the notification feature for this?

Comment: are you running your boot client from IDE ? if yes, then please try it run spring boot client and admin from terminal, I have faced same issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the application through the command line from your project directory -

> mvn spring-boot:run

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

```
spring.boot.admin.auto-deregistration=true
```

Set this in your application.properties.

Keep in mind, this only works when your application is terminated gracefully or using SIGTERM (`kill -15 PID`).

In case you kill your application, the app won't deregister itself because the context was not closed properly.

See more here- https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#spring-boot-admin-client